# VBScript converting files and locking it with an unknown password

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I was writing and testing a series of useful(?) scripts with VBScript. This script works, it does convert the file from CSV to XLSX, and more... However: it locks each XLS* file with an unknown password whenever it converts it. I currently don't have any explanation, do you? :)

```
Option Explicit
'------------------------------------------------------------------
'          Author: Fabio Craig Wimmer Florey (@robomancy)
'   Last Modified: 2021 - 04 - 09 (yyyy - MM - dd)
'        Modifica:         
'------------------------------------------------------------------
'                          0.1 FUNCTIONS
'  - IIf:       Ternary operator for VBScript
'  - Contains:  Just like InStr(), but it return booleans 
'  - GetFiles:  Returns a list of files in a given directory
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Function IIf(bClause, vTrue, vFalse)
    If CBool(bClause) Then
        IIf = vTrue
    Else 
        IIf = vFalse
    End If
End Function
Function Contains(sText, sFind)
    Contains = IIf (InStr(1, sText, sFind, 0) > 0, True, False)
End Function
Function GetFiles(sPath)
Dim oFileSystem, oFolder, oFiles
Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder(sPath)
Set GetFiles = oFolder.Files
Set oFileSystem = Nothing
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'                       0.2 SUBROUTINES
'  - ReFormatExcel:  Converts each file with a given extension
'                    in another file with a given extesion.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ReFormatExcel(sPath,firstExt,secondExt, convNumber)
' Check the right convNumber at:
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat 
Dim oFileSystem, oFile
Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each oFile in GetFiles(sPath)
    If LCase(oFileSystem.GetExtensionName(oFile.Path)) = firstExt Then
    Dim nPath
    Dim oExcel, Wb
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.Visible       = False
    Set Wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
    nPath = Replace(oFile.Path,"."&firstExt,"."&secondExt)
    Call Wb.SaveAs(nPath, convNumber, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True)
    Wb.Close False
    oExcel.Quit 
    Set Wb = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    oFileSystem.DeleteFile oFile.Path
    End If
Next
Set oFileSystem = Nothing
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' 1.0 ARGUMENTS
'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' 1.1 SCRIPT
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Call ReFormatExcel("myPath\test\","csv","xlsx",51)
```

---

Bonus question: Do you have any other function\sub you think is useful to write?

Comment: See the parameters of [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas).

Comment: i.e. you're using `0` as the password in `Call Wb.SaveAs(nPath, convNumber, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True)`.

Comment: Solved! Thank you, @BigBen, I guess it's been a long day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it looks like you are assigning 0 to all optional values when you call the following.

```
Call Wb.SaveAs(nPath, convNumber, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

| Name | Required/Optional | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Password | Optional | Variant | A case-sensitive string (no more than 15 characters) that indicates the protection password to be given to the file. |